# Type error in generator , haskell list using tuple

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

Currently working with Haskell on a function that takes a String in parameters and return a **list of (Char, Int)** The function occur works with multiple type and is used in the function called **word**.

```
occur::Eq a=>a->[a]->Int
occur n [] = 0
occur n (x:xs) = if n == x
              then 1 + occur n xs
              else occur n xs

word::String->[(String,Int)]
word xs = [(x,y) | x<-head xs, y<-(occur x xs)]
```

**Get me this error**

```
ERROR "file.hs":31 - Type error in generator
*** Term           : head xs
*** Type           : Char
*** Does not match : [a]
```

What am I doing wrong ? How can I make this code run properly , type-wise ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you say that `xs` has type `String`, so `head xs` has type `Char`, and then you try to iterate over a single `Char`, which can't be done.  The `a <- b` syntax only works when `b` is a list.  You have the same problem in that `y <- occur x xs` is trying to iterate over a single `Int`, not a list of `Int`.  You also had a problem in your type signature, the first type in the tuple should be `Char`, not `String`.  You can fix it with:

```
word :: String -> [(Char, Int)]
word xs = [(x, occur x xs) | x <- xs]
```

Here we loop over the entire string `xs`, and for each character `x` in `xs` we compute `occur x xs`.

---

I would actually recommend using a slightly stronger constraint than just `Eq`.  If you generalize `word` (that I've renamed to `occurrences`) and constrain it with `Ord`, you can use `group` and `sort`, which allow you to keep from iterating over the list repeatedly for each character and avoid the `O(n^2)` complexity.  You can also simplify the definition pretty significantly:

```
import Control.Arrow
import Data.List

occurrences :: Ord a => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
occurrences = map (head &&& length) . group . sort
```

What this does is first sort your list, then group by identical elements.  So `"Hello, world"` turns into

```
> sort "Hello, world"
" ,Hdellloorw"
> group $ sort "Hello, world"
[" ", ",", "H", "d", "e", "lll", "oo", "r", "w"]
```

Then we use the arrow operator `&&&` which takes two functions, applies a single input to both, then return the results as a tuple.  So `head &&& length` is the same as saying

```
\x -> (head x, length x)
```

and we map this over our sorted, grouped list:

```
> map (head &&& length) $ group $ sort "Hello, world"
[(' ',1),(',',1),('H',1),('d',1),('e',1),('l',3),('o',2),('r',1),('w',1)]
```

This eliminates repeats, you aren't having to scan the list over and over counting the number of elements, and it can be defined in a single line in the pointfree style, which is nice.  However, it does not preserve order.  If you need to preserve order, I would then use `sortBy` and the handy function `comparing` from `Data.Ord` (but we lose a nice point free form):

```
import Control.Arrow
import Data.List
import Data.Ord (comparing)

occurrences :: Ord a => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
occurrences = map (head &&& length) . group . sort

occurrences' :: Ord a => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
occurrences' xs = sortBy (comparing ((`elemIndex` xs) . fst)) $ occurrences xs
```

You can almost read this as plain English.  This sorts by comparing the index in `xs` of the first element of the tuples in `occurrences xs`.  Even though `elemIndex` returns a value of type `Maybe Int`, we can still compare those directly (`Nothing` is "less than" any `Just` value).  It simply looks up the first index of each letter in the original string and sorts by that index.  That way

```
> occurrences' "Hello, world"
```

returns

```
[('H',1),('e',1),('l',3),('o',2),(',',1),(' ',1),('w',1),('r',1),('d',1)]
```

with all the letters in the original order, up to repetition.